# Java/Spark: how to find key with max value in a col with array of struct of map

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, aggregation, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataframe, and I want to fetch the key with max value in a map.

dataframe creation:

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark.read()
                .option("header", "true")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .csv("/home/path/to/file/verify.csv");
//loading Spark ML model
PipelineModel gloveModel = PipelineModel.load("models/gloveModel");
Dataset<Row> df = gloveModel.transform(data);
```

df.printSchema();

```
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- class: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- result: string (nullable = true)     
 |    |    |-- metadata: map (nullable = true)      
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

// the field with map entries is as below:

df.select("class.metadata").show(10,50);

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                         metadata|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  [[Sports -> 3.2911853E-9, Business -> 5.1852658E-6, World -> 3.96135E-9, Sci/Tech -> 0.9999949, sentence -> 0]]|
|      [[Sports -> 1.9902605E-10, Business -> 1.0305631E-8, World -> 1.0, Sci/Tech -> 3.543277E-9, sentence -> 0]]|
|    [[Sports -> 1.0, Business -> 8.1944885E-12, World -> 4.554111E-13, Sci/Tech -> 1.7239962E-12, sentence -> 0]]|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**I would like to achieve below result**(highest value in each map of a row):

```
+--------------+
|    prediction|
+--------------+
|      Sci/Tech|
|         World|
|        Sports|
+--------------+
```

I have tried:

df.select(map_values(col("class.metadata"))).show(10, 50);
but ended up with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'map_values(`class`.`metadata`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires map type, however, '`class`.`metadata`' is of array<map<string,string>> type.;;
'Project [map_values(class#95.metadata) AS map_values(class.metadata)#106]...
```

df.select(flatten(col("class"))).show();
errored with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'flatten(`class`)' due to data type mismatch: The argument should be an array of arrays, but '`class`' is of array<struct<annotatorType:string,begin:int,end:int,result:string,metadata:map<string,string>,embeddings:array<float>>> type.;;
'Project [flatten(class#95) AS flatten(class)#106]
```

My Spark SQL version is 2.4.0 (where explode function is deprecated)

Any suggestions/advice are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post dataframe creation code ?

Comment: yes, added as per my latest edits

Comment: Also please post same records from  your csv file.

Comment: explode function is deprecated, instead of that you can use org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode method. Please check below answer which i have used.

Comment: Hi @Sandesh Mendon, Have you checked my answer? please accept + upvote if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`class.metadata` is of type Array of Map type. But `map_values` function only takes Map type.

Use `explode` to extract map from array of data & then pass that map data to map_values function. Please check below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

df.select(explode($"class.metadata").as("metadata")).select(map_values($"metadata")).show(false)
```

Comment: As I mentioned my end goal is to find max value among map values, could you help me get that.

Comment: The column "class.metadata" is part of a dataframe produced by Spark ML method called '.transform()' - so no point in giving my input dataset

Answer (score 1):

This is how I tackle it-

```
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      Row(Seq(Map("Sports" -> "3.291185", "Business" -> "5.18526",
      "World" -> "3.9613", "Sci/Tech" -> "0.9999949", "sentence" -> "0"))),
      Row( Seq( Map("Sports" -> "1.9902605", "Business" -> "1.030563", "World" -> "1.0",
        "Sci/Tech" -> "3.54327", "sentence" -> "0")),
      Row(Seq( Map("Sports" -> "1.0", "Business" -> "8.194488", "World" -> "4.5541",
        "Sci/Tech" -> "1.723996", "sentence" -> "0")))
    )))
   val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,
     StructType(Array(StructField("metadata", ArrayType(MapType(StringType, StringType))))))

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    df.selectExpr()

    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |metadata                                                                                          |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |[[Sports -> 3.291185, Business -> 5.18526, World -> 3.9613, Sci/Tech -> 0.9999949, sentence -> 0]]|
    |[[Sports -> 1.9902605, Business -> 1.030563, World -> 1.0, Sci/Tech -> 3.54327, sentence -> 0]]   |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    root
    |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- key: string
    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Please try this-

```
 val keyWithMaxVal = udf((am: Map[String, String]) =>
      am.mapValues(_.toDouble).toSeq.maxBy(_._2)._1,
      StringType
    )
    df.select(explode(col("metadata")).as("exploded_meta"))
      .select(keyWithMaxVal(col("exploded_meta")).as("prediction"))
      .show(false)
    +----------+
    |prediction|
    +----------+
    |Business  |
    |Sci/Tech  |
    +----------+
```